# Set limit on callproc method in psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm using psycopg2 to manipulate a postgreSQL database.

I'm using the `callproc` method a lot because it is very convenient to directly pass procedure responses to new procedure calls.

However, I need to get the first line of the response of a procedure call returning a huge number of rows.

The classical way to do so is something like:

```
cursor.callproc(<proc-path>, <proc-parameters>)
data = cursor.fetchone()
```

But as there is a huge quantity of data which are retrieved, this takes 7 seconds.

When I simply call:

```
cursor.execute("select * from <proc-path>(<proc-parameters-as-a-string>) limit 1")
cursor.fetchone() # more or less equivalent to cursor.fetchall() here
```

The result just comes in the blink of an eye. However this implies converting parameters manually to something understandable as a string by the database, which is not convenient.

Is there a way using `callproc` or something equivalent to limit the server response to `N` elements only?

Comment: I don't understand why you need to make the execute string yourself.  Why not just do `cursor.execute("select * from my_function(%s, %s, %s, %s) limit 1", [param1, param2, param3, param4])`?

Comment: Is it certain that psycopg2 exclusively uses the `__str__` method for suitable conversions? For instance, if I have types like timestamps, will `__str__` method directly applied on a datetime.datetime object be understood by the procedure?

Comment: psycopg2 handles the type conversion for you, but it doesn't necessarily use `__str__`.  %s is just a placeholder for psycopg2 and is used for every type.